# This predefined function slowing down my program's performance

Tags: c++, performance, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, std

I am working on a PCL (Point Cloud Library) project. One part of it requires me to clip point clouds, for which I need to know the minimum and maximum coordinates of given point cloud.

PCL provides a predefined function called **getminmax3d()**. I tried and It works well, The only problem is, It takes a lot of time when I input a large point cloud file. I made my own definition of getminmax3d() and it takes lesser time. I am not understanding why these two behave like this.

I tried with 5 point cloud data files. In all cases, program that uses predefined function takes long time as compare to the program for which I defined the definition.

Here is the code: 
First implementation - It uses predefined function getminmax3d()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/common/common.h>

int main (int, char**)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud;
  cloud = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("your_pcd_file.pcd", *cloud);
  pcl::PointXYZ minPt, maxPt;
  pcl::getMinMax3D (*cloud, minPt, maxPt);
  std::cout << "Max x: " << maxPt.x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Max y: " << maxPt.y << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Max z: " << maxPt.z << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Min x: " << minPt.x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Min y: " << minPt.y << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Min z: " << minPt.z << std::endl;
  return (0);
}
```

Second implementation - This source code uses a user-defined function definition to replace functionality of **getminmax3d()**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/common/time.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
   if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("rhino.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
   {
     PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file rhino.pcd \n");
     return (-1);
   }
   float min_x = cloud->points[0].x, min_y = cloud->points[0].y, min_z = cloud->points[0].z, max_x = cloud->points[0].x, max_y = cloud->points[0].y, max_z = cloud->points[0].z;
   pcl::StopWatch watch;
   for (size_t i = 1; i < cloud->points.size (); ++i){
       if(cloud->points[i].x <= min_x )
           min_x = cloud->points[i].x;
       else if(cloud->points[i].y <= min_y )
           min_y = cloud->points[i].y;
       else if(cloud->points[i].z <= min_z )
           min_z = cloud->points[i].z;
       else if(cloud->points[i].x >= max_x )
           max_x = cloud->points[i].x;
       else if(cloud->points[i].y >= max_y )
           max_y = cloud->points[i].y;
       else if(cloud->points[i].z >= max_z )
           max_z = cloud->points[i].z;
   }
   pcl::console::print_highlight ("Time taken: %f\n", watch.getTimeSeconds());
   std::cout << "Min x: " << min_x <<"\t";
   std::cout << "Max x: " << max_x << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Min y: " << min_y <<"\t";
   std::cout << "Max y: " << max_y << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Min z: " << min_z <<"\t";
   std::cout << "Max z: " << max_z << std::endl;
   return (0);
}
```

I tried both programs on following 5 point cloud files.
[image: Armadillo]
[image: Bunny]
[image: Dragon]
[image: Buddha]
[image: Rhino]

Result obtained: 
**ttf** : Time taken factor 
**ttf** = 15 means user definition is about 15 times faster than predefined functions. ttf value is measured by taking average of 10 trials for both implementations.

```
PCD file    Filetype   File size    ttf
Rhino.pcd   XYZ        2.57 MB      15.260
Bun_zipper  XYZCI      1.75 MB      17.422
Armadillo   XYZ        5.26 MB      15.847
Dragon_vrip XYZ        14.7 MB      17.013
Happy_vrip  XYZ        18.0 MB      14.981
```

I am wondering why predefined function is taking more time? I want to reduce my program source code lines. I've always believed that using standard header files and their function gives you best performance, But in this case it seems to fail.

[This is where you can find standard definition.](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.2/a01371_source.html#l00212)
Would anyone please help me to find out why second implementation takes less times(approx 15 times), even the standard definition of getminmax3d() is similar to mine.

Comment: Did you mean http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.2/a02405.html#ga3166f09aafd659f69dc75e63f5e10f81 as the documentation link? Your sample code calls a 3-argument version of the function but you link to one with many args

Comment: Well documented question, upvoted. About the "I've always believed that using standard header files and their function gives you best performance": it's not always like that. Often standard functions have to deal with corner cases which are not useful to your specific case, or are overly general, or are compiled with an older compiler version, with less aggressive optimization settings or with optimizations targeted to older processors. Rewriting your own version targeted to your specific needs in such cases can be a valid possibility (as long as your version performs correctly =) ).

Comment: @M.M OOps.... Lemme find it again.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I agree. This completely works. I am using second implementation, It takes less time. But I want to use predefined function with same performance.

Comment: Are you using -O3 (or whatever your compiler's max optimization level is)?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic allocation? Does it make a difference? Further, the library is open source, so please extract the according function and take a look at it, maybe that would already have answered your question.

Comment: It looks like you wrote some code that is faster than the predefined function... that happens sometimes . The predefined function handles various cases of input whereas yours only handles one case. Perhaps you could post to the PCL mailing list about this case , their implementation makes many function calls (returning data by value for each point) and maybe they figured a compiler would optimize that out but it turned out your compiler didn't.

Comment: It might be possible to compare assembly for the predefined function vs. your loop and see what it is getting hung up on

Comment: @M.M Kindly check again. I've updated my link. This gives you definition. Hope it helps.  No I am not using -o3

Comment: @M.M Please help me. I feel like there is some incompleteness and my implementation can get me trouble for some other data files. How can I just have same run-time performance using predefined getminmax() function.

Comment: First of all , use `-O3` .. performance questions are meaningless if you do not use the max optimization level

Comment: apart from that, your only other option is to edit the predefined function to incorporate your improvements. I'm not sure what answer you expect here,  the predefined function is what it is, you can't wave a magic wand and have things go faster.

Answer (score 1):

`pcl::getMinMax3D` has a very inefficient implementation. To search for the minimum and max point it does the following:

```
Eigen::Array4f min_p, max_p;
min_p.setConstant (FLT_MAX);
max_p.setConstant (-FLT_MAX);
for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size (); ++i)
{
   // ... (check the validity of the point if it is not a dense cloud)

   pcl::Array4fMapConst pt = cloud.points[i].getArray4fMap ();
   min_p = min_p.min (pt);
   max_p = max_p.max (pt);
}
```

And if you check for the `getArray4fMap()` function:

```
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array4f, Eigen::Aligned> Array4fMap;

inline pcl::Array4fMap getArray4fMap() const { 
    return (pcl::Array4fMap(data)); 
}
```

For each point in the cloud it is constructing an `Eigen::Map` and then comparing it against the current minimum and maximum points. This is VERY inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The predefined function `pcl::getMinMax3D` is able to be faster with optimization flags set and in Release. Since if SSE intrinsics are used by Eigen, then the operations happen on 4 aligned bytes.

More information at
https://gitter.im/PointCloudLibrary/pcl?at=5e3899d06f9d3d34981c0687